# How to access another image in docker compose?

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose, inertiajs

Here is my docker compose file for a Laravel project:

```
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: ./dockerfiles
      dockerfile: nginx.dockerfile
      args:
        - UID=${UID:-1000}
        - GID=${GID:-1000}
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html:delegated
    depends_on:
      - php
    networks:
      - laravel

  php:
    build:
      context: ./dockerfiles
      dockerfile: php.dockerfile
      args:
        - UID=${UID:-1000}
        - GID=${GID:-1000}
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html:delegated
    networks:
      - laravel

  npm:
    image: node:current-alpine
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    entrypoint: [ 'npm' ]
    networks:
      - laravel

  artisan:
    build:
      context: ./dockerfiles
      dockerfile: php.dockerfile
      args:
        - UID=${UID:-1000}
        - GID=${GID:-1000}
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html:delegated
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    entrypoint: [ 'php', '/var/www/html/artisan' ]
    networks:
      - laravel
```

I can use artisan fine, but there is an artisan command that uses node internally and I don't know how to have artisan be able to use node in docker. So running this:

```
docker compose run --rm artisan inertia:start-ssr
```

outputs this:

```
sh:
exec: line 0: node: not found
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems your application does not have installed dependencies. First of all, you should install and run Node:

```
docker-compose run npm bash // go inside node container

npm install && npm run dev // install
```

Then you could initialize inertia.

But for proper installation, I recommend you read the [official documentation](https://inertiajs.com/server-side-rendering)